# DeterministicTaskScheduler vs AsyncContext in unit tests

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

What are the differences between using dependency injection with [DeterministicTaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818494.aspx) and [AsyncContext](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncContext.md) in unit tests? The code in the production always run on `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: How is dependency injection related to this?

Comment: Dependency injection is one of many ways to allow the code to schedule tasks on `DeterministicTaskScheduler` in unit tests but on `TaskScheduler.Default` in production. The author of the scheduler also used dependency injection in the example. Specifying dependency injection is to be more specific in the question.